# Why does execute () append null values and executemany() doesn't?

Tags: python, mysql

While using MySQL through python, on using execute() function null values are getting updated in the specific table, but on using executemany() the null values are returning errors.

The working commands:

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO users (name, fav) VALUES('John', null)"

mydb.commit()
```

The code that doesn't work:

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, fav) VALUES(%s, %s)"

val =[
        ('Samantha', 154),
        ('Thalia', 155),
        ('Jacobs', null),
        ('Jamie', null)
]

mycursor.executemany(sql, val)

mydb.commit()
```

The error generated is as follows:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo_python.py", line 14, in 
    ('Jacobs', null),
NameError: name 'null' is not defined

Comment: This isn't Java or Javascript. Equivalent to `null` is `None`

Comment: `null` is not a valid python literal, it is being interpreted as a variable name, which isn't defined, and thus, your interpreter is complaining you are using an undefined variable. Use `None`

Comment: `null` is valid in SQL code, but not in Python code.  Use `None` instead.

Comment: Thanks guys!!! It worked!!! thank you so much

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga If that is the case, I think in the execute command it is working as the whole string is being passed to SQL without any python interpretation.... But in the executemany() function, due to use of tuples, python is the one parsing it at run time and hence returning error.

Comment: You would have the same problem if you use `execute()` with the values coming from Python, e.g. `mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO users (name, fav) VALUES(%s, %s)", ("John", null))`